# Does Spring XwsSecurityInterceptor remove the Security element from Header?

Tags: spring, security, soap, ws-security

I have implemented Spring [XwsSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html) and receiving soap message with `<wsse:UsernameToken/>` inside the `<wsse:Security/>` tag ([OASIS WS-Security](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf)). It works fine.

Now I am trying to implement a logging interceptor to log the request/response soap messages in DB.

I can get the Security element in **`getSource()`** method of my custom logging interceptor (which extends `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor`):

```java
@Override
protected Source getSource(WebServiceMessage message) {
    SaajSoapMessage soap = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
    logger.info(Utils.getSoapEnvelopeAsString(soap));
    // this envelop contains the <wsse:Security/> element as expected
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

**But My problem is**, when I extract the envelop inside my endpoint method, I don't get the **`<wsse:Security/>`** element in the header anymore.

```java
public JAXBElement<MyResponseType> getRecepientInfo(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<MyRequestType> request, MessageContext messageContext) {
    SaajSoapMessage soapReq = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
    logger.info(Utils.getSoapEnvelope(soapReq));
    // this envelop doesn't contain the <wsse:Security/> element
}
```

Here is the code for `Utils.getSoapEnvelope(soap)`:

```java
public static String getSoapEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage soapMessage) {
    SoapEnvelope envelope = soapMessage.getEnvelope();
    String envelopeMessge = "";
    try {
        envelopeMessge = Utils.getSourceAsString(envelope.getSource());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO handle Exception here.
    }
    return envelopeMessge;
}

public static String getSourceAsString(Source source) throws Exception{
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer xform = tfactory.newTransformer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
    xform.transform(source, result);

    return writer.toString();
}
```

Does spring remove the **`<wsse:Security/>`** element from the header after authentication has been completed? Or, I am doing something wrong here?

How should I get the **`<wsse:Security/>`** element from header **inside endpoint method**?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ? I'm currently facing the same problem.

Comment: No @JimmySelgenNielsen , I didn't find anything

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any resolution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer but for whom it may interest I found out how to solve this.

You need to modify your **securityPolicy.xml** file so that the security header is kept. Simply set the attribute `retainSecurityHeader` to true. Here is an example of such a file:

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration retainSecurityHeader="true" dumpMessages="false" xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
    <xwss:UsernameToken digestPassword="false" useNonce="false" id="someId"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. This also helps in case another EndpointInterceptor that is invoked after the  XwsSecurityInterceptor needs to access the UsernameToken.